# Extract luminance data using ffmpeg libavfilter, specifically PIX_FMT_YUV420P type

Tags: c, ffmpeg, video-processing

This pertains to ffmpeg 0.7 (yes I know it's old, but data access should be similar).

I am writing a libavfilter to extract the luminance data from each frame.  In draw_slice() function I have access to AVFilterLink structure which in turn gives me access to AVFilterBufferRef structure that have uint8_t *data[] pointers.  With the PIX_FMT_YUV420P type, I think data[0], data[1], data[2] refers to Y U V channels respectively.

My question is, with the pointer to data[0] (luminance plane), how do I interpret the data?  The pixfmt.h header file states:

> PIX_FMT_YUV420P,   ///< planar YUV 4:2:0, 12bpp, (1 Cr & Cb sample per 2x2 Y samples)

does that mean I have to interpret the luminance plane data every 2 bytes?  Also, what exactly is the datatype for the values pointed to by the pointer - int, float, etc?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes data[0] is luminance. It is 8 bits (one byte) per pixel. but you must watch the line stride.

So to look at every pixel in a loop:

```
uint8_t pixval;
for(int y = 0 ; y < height; ++y )
{
    for(int x = 0 ; x < width; ++x )
    {
        pixval = data[0][x+(y*stride)];
    }
}
```

(obviously, you could optimize this)

The U and V planes are one quarter (half the height and half the width) the resolution of the Y plane. So each byte is 4 pixels (2 wide 2 tall).